# Why my Node.js server is listening to port and Adonis.js not?

Tags: javascript, node.js, adonis.js

My English is poor sorry.
I'm using AdonisJs, but have a problem. 
Adonis console running and showing no error but host not working.
You can see the problem from below screenshot

I'm running vagrant and here's my `vagrantfile`.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 3000
  config.vm.synced_folder "app", "/home/vagrant/app"
end
```

[AdonisJS Running screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAMHd.jpg)

[NodeJS Running screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQSou.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Your Adonis application is running on port 8000 but you are using the port 3000 in your Vagrant configuration.

You may change one of those.

You can change Adonis port in the `.env` file at the root of your project.

Comment: Man i have put the wrong screen display i am still having problems. Adonis does not work on 8000 port

Comment: So may you clarify some information. What's your Node.js version? What's AdonisJs version? What happened when you are trying to reach your application? On which port AdonisJs run?

Comment: I am working on my Windows operating system and the adonis project is running. I think I'm having problems with vagrant * host * settings.

Answer (score 0):

Your Adonis app is running on port 8000 from the screenshot you shared. But, your Vagrant is looking at host 3000.